# Delete new record if same data exists

Tags: sql, records

I want to delete new record if the same record created before.

My columns are date, time and MsgLog. If date and time are same,  I want to delete new one.

I need help .

Comment: You should set in database to allow only unique, so new record won't be added.

Comment: but how can i make all of column UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the table whether that value exists or not in the column using a query. If it exists, you can show message that a record already exists.

Comment: how can ı create that query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid deleting by checking for duplicate while inserting.
Just modify your insert procedure like this, so no duplicates will entered.

```
declare @intCount as int;

select @intCount =count(MsgLog) where (date=@date) and (time =@time )

if @intCount=0
begin

'insert procedure

end

> Edited
```

since what you wanted is you need to delete the duplicate entries after your bulk insert. Think about this logic,

1. create a temporary table
2. Insert LogId,date,time from your table to the temp table order by date,time
3. now declare four variables, @preTime,@PreDate,@CurrTime,@CurrDate
4. Loop for each items in temp table,  like this

   while
   begin

   @pkLogID= ' Get LogID for the current row

   select @currTime=time,@currDate=date from tblTemp where pkLogId=@pkLogID 'Assign Current values

   'Delete condition check

   if (@currDate=@preDate) and (@currTime=@preTime)

   begin
   delete from MAINTABLE where pkLogId=@pkLogID 
   end

   select @preDate=@currDate,@preTime=@currTime 'Assign current values as preValues for next entries

   end

The above strategy is we sorted all entries according to date and time, so duplicates will come closer, and we started to compare each entry with its previous, when match found we deleting the duplicate entry.

Comment: Thanks. But really i dont understand what code wants to do :(

Comment: i work with job Agent. I get datas from txt file. here is codes i m working with                                                         bulk insert taskytablo
from '\\10.24.90.10\data_history\VD_AlarmLog.001'
with (fieldterminator = '  ',  rowterminator =  '\n' )
go

Answer (score 0):

To *prevent* such kind of erroneous additions you can add restriction to your table to ensure *unique @Date @Time pairs*;  if you don't want to change data structure (e.g. you want to add records with such restrictions once or twice) you can exploit `insert select` counstruction.

```
-- MS SQL version, check your DBMS
insert into MyTable(
  Date,
  Time,
  MsgLog)
 select @Date,
        @Time,
        @MsgLog
  where not exists(
          select 1
            from MyTable
           where (@Date = Date) and
                 (@Time = Time)
        )
```

P.S. *want to delete new one* equals to *do not insert new one*

Comment: Really Thanks.. Here is my codes i m working with. i m working in agent job. ---> insert taskytablo from '\\10.24.90.10\data_history\VD_AlarmLog.001' with (fieldterminator = ' ', rowterminator = '\n' ) go ---> so how can i update these in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a unique constraint in the DB level to avoid invalid data no matter who writes to your DB.
It's always important to have your schema well defined. That way you're safe that no matter how many apps are using your DB or even in case someone just writes some inserts manually.

I don't know which DB are you using but in MySQL can use to following DDL

```
alter table MY_TABLE add unique index(date, time);
```

And in Oracle you can :

```
alter table MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT constaint_name UNIQUE (date, time);
```

That said, you can also (not instead of) do some checks before inserting new values to avoid dealing with exceptions or to improve performance by avoiding making unnecessary access to your DB (length \ nulls for example could easily be dealt with in the application level).

Comment: Thanks so much. I m working with mssql and agent job. Is there any differences betweetn mysql and sql about that code above u wrote ?

Comment: It should be similar to Oracle.